# Image is not displaying correctly on chrome browser

Tags: image, browser, mosaic

From some days ago, images are not displaying correctly in my browser(chrome). It's displaying with mosaic effect like following screenshot.

[image]

Is this virus or what? If virus, how to fix this? (If I refresh page, it displays well, but a few mins later it doesn't display well again.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off **[GPU rasterization]** and **[hardware acceleration]** is worked for me.
(Windows 10 + Chrome v101.x)

#### Turning off GPU rasterization

1. Go to `chrome://flags`
2. Select '**Disabled**' right side of '**GPU rasterization**'.
3. Restart browser.

#### Turning off hardware acceleration

1. Go to `chrome://settings/system`
2. Move switch off '**Use hardware acceleration when available**'.
3. Restart browser.